# C# Managed DirectX sprite2D locating bug?

Tags: c#, directx, sprite, game-engine, managed

I want to draw 2D sprite.
And here is strange thing: if i `Sprite.Draw2D` with first overload:

```
using (Sprite Spr = new Sprite(Gfx))
{
  Spr.Begin(SpriteFlags.AlphaBlend);
  int SprY = Gfx.PresentationParameters.BackBufferHeight/2;    
  int SprX = Gfx.PresentationParameters.BackBufferWidth/2;   
  Spr.Draw2D(Tex, new Point(0,0), 0.0f, new Point(SprX,SprY), Color.White);
  Spr.End();
  while (!Spr.Disposed)
    Spr.Dispose();
}
```

It locating right in 128,128.
But I want to scale-down my image.
So i use 3rd overload of `Sprite.Draw2D`:

```
Spr.Draw2D(Tex, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 1024), new Rectangle(0,0,256,256), new Point(SprX,SprY) , Color.White);
```

Then, it draws to weired position(but correct-sized).
I found-out that width of screen in case of 3rd overload = 1280.
And no matter of `PresentationParameters` or `ViewPort` sizes. Even on other machine it is 1280, and center will be 640.

I've tryed to debug Gfx(Device) object and see if any appereance of '1280' number, and it is appear in `Gfx.DisplayMode`. Unfortunatly, i cant set this parameter because "Device.SetDisplayMode is deprecated" as MSDN says. And DisplayMode.Width is differs between two computers i've test my 'game' on.

Probably i've missed something realy HUGE and stack on it.

By the way, im using DirectX libs from `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0"` if this matters.

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated library instead of, say, SharpDX?

Comment: @Asik I dont want third-part libs in my project.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no currently supported library from Microsoft for using Direct3D from managed code, so you'll have to switch to native code if you don't want to use any non-Microsoft library.

Comment: @Asik Oh, can you give more info on this?

Comment: Not sure what info you want, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769064.aspx is the getting started page. Not sure why you'd *really* not want to use SharpDX instead, it's a thin, 99% auto-generated wrapper over the official API, widely used and well supported, and it'll be immensely easier than switching to C++ just to not use non-Microsoft code.